# Order of Forcebuild publisher in CruiseControl

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Is there a way to order the execution of a force build publisher and wait for the prior forcebuild to finish up before executing the next one?

```
<publishers>
    <forcebuild>
        <project>Project A</project>
    </forcebuild>

    <forcebuild>
        <project>Project B</project>
    </forcebuild>

    <forcebuild>
        <project>Project C</project>
    </forcebuild>
</publishers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the project [in the same queue and set their priorities](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Integration+Queues) to order the correctly. I've never used queues in the same situation but it should have the desired effect.

Comment: The issue that I am trying to resolve is that lets say ProjectA is set as priority 1 and ProjectB set as priority 2. They are both in the same queue. However ProjectA has triggers that depends on other project and I need those dependency projects to complete before executing projectB. I have tried setting the priorities on the dependency projects but because there is lag time triggering the dependency project it goes to ProjectB right after. I wish there is a waitTime attribute for forcebuild publisher.

Comment: So you need those other projects to be built between ProjectA and ProjectB? Couldn't you then perhaps put them in the same queue and set their priority values between the priorities of ProjectA and ProjectB?

Comment: Yes I did that but due to the there is no lag time between ProjectA and ProjectB, cruiseControl would sometime start building ProjectB then start queueing the dependencies of ProjectA.